# Create a shareable Image/ certificate in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I want to be able to create some kind of certificate of completion. The layout will be always the same, but picture and text in it should change. This certificate should be created in a jpg format, so I can share it with other apps.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be accomplished?

The only way I can imagine is that I create a Screen template where I put in text and picture, then let the phone take a screenshot and save that screenshot automatically. But this might lead to unwanted content in the picture and different image sizes. I have searched for Widgets/ ways to create an image in Flutter but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a widget with constructors (Image and text).

Then use a flutter package called screenshot to capture the parent widget as image and save it to the users phone.

plugin link: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot